# Why any problem can be reduced to SAT is NP-Complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, p-vs-np

I have a book statement says the title, I don't understand it. From my current understanding if a problem A can be reduced to a problem B then it only means B is at least as difficult as A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed that is **incorrect**. All problems in $\mathbf{P}$ are reducible to SAT. In fact, even trivial problems (e.g., finite languages) are reducible to SAT.

What *is* probably meant is that, if a problem in $\mathbf{NP}$ is such that SAT is reducible to it, then it is $\mathbf{NP}$-complete.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also suspected that the book is incorrect.

Comment: I might be missing something but " if a problem A can be reduced to a problem B then it only means B is at least as difficult as A" is not an incorrect statement.

Comment: @Auberon Indeed. The "incorrect" statement is the one in the question title.